# Assembly CALL and RET stack

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have question.When I know that

```
call <address>
```

is equivalent to

```
push rip  
jmp <address>
```

and I also know that

```
ret
```

is equivalent to

```
pop rip
jmp <rip>
```

But if we jump to rip why don’t we start this loop again because we push rip before jump and rip specify on jump? Can you explain how do we pass this jump in code

Comment: Because RIP always points to the next instruction to be executed - not the current instruction.

Comment: From Intel's manual: _"3.5  INSTRUCTION POINTER
The instruction pointer (EIP) register contains the offset in the current code segment for **the next** instruction to be executed"_.

Comment: It’s right but when we push it specifing on next instruction(jump) and when we pop it,it still specify on jump

Comment: But thank to Mr. Doug Currie I understand it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various processors have different ways of handling this. On some, the `call` pushes the address of the instruction after the call. On others, the `ret` adds the length of the call instruction to the return address before jumping.

The first method is more flexible because it makes it possible to use various addressing modes with different instruction lengths in the `call`. It's also likely that the instruction decoder already knows the location of the next instruction as the `call` is being processed.

Comment: For x86, `call` pushes the address of the instruction after the call.  That's the current RIP value while the call is executing; RIP-relative addressing modes work the same way, relative to the end of the instruction.  x86 instructions aren't fixed length, so there's no way for `ret` to know whether it was called by a 5-byte `call <rel32>` (or some prefixes in front of that, e.g. from a linker "relaxing" another encoding), or  2-byte `call rax` indirect, a 6  byte `call [rel func_ptr]`, or 7 or 8-byte `call [rdi + r10*8 + jump_table_base]`